# can't connect to interbase using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, odbc, sqlconnection, interbase

i'm pretty new in VB.NET.

i'm trying to connect INTERBASE database (local) and get an error:

[image]

I've tried many things and nothing helped.
can't figure out what am I doing wrong or missed

```
Imports FirebirdSql

Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim query As String = "select * from EMPLOYEE"
    Dim csb As FbConnectionStringBuilder
    Dim cnn As New FbConnection

    csb = New FbConnectionStringBuilder()
    csb.DataSource = "LOCALHOST"
    csb.ServerType = 0
    csb.Database = "c:\db\office.gdb"
    csb.UserID = "SYSDBA"
    csb.Password = "masterkey"

    cnn = New FbConnection(csb.ToString)

    Dim da As New FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbDataAdapter(query, cnn)
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim dt As New DataTable

    Try
        cnn.Open()
        da.Fill(dt)
        cnn.Close()
        cnn.Dispose()

        Dim ans As String

        If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
                ans = Convert.ToString(row.Item(1))
                TextBox1.Text = ans
            Next
        Else
            TextBox1.Text = "Record Not Found"
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error: " & ex.Message, "Error")
    End Try

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Does it work with _ans = Convert.ToString(row.Item(0))_ ?

Comment: That doesnt sound like a connection problem at all.  What line do you get the exception on?  remember, collections and such are zero based - the first item will be `Item(1)`

Comment: nop, in debug mode it stops on `cnn.open()` and throw attached error

Comment: cnn.open is a bit too early. I doubt row.item(1) might be causing this problem.

Comment: after delete all `IF` statment include `FOR` loop still get error on `cnn.Open()` :(

Comment: Have a look here: https://www.connectionstrings.com/interbase/

Comment: As far as I know you cannot use the Firebird .NET provider to connect to InterBase.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `FirebirdClient` to connect to InterBase. Firebird and InterBase are not the same.

Answer (score 1):

So...!!!
After digging the net I finally got it working!

1. Installed "Firebird_ODBC_2.0.3.154_Win32.exe" Downloaded from http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/odbc-driver/
2. fixed my script:

   ```
   Dim query As String = "select * from EMPLOYEE"
   Dim cnn As New Odbc.OdbcConnection()
   Dim estring As New Odbc.OdbcConnectionStringBuilder("DRIVER=Firebird/InterBase(r) driver;UID=SYSDBA;PWD=masterkey;DBNAME=128.1.7.81:C:\office\db\office.gdb;")
   cnn = New OdbcConnection(estring.ToString)

   Dim da As New OdbcDataAdapter("select * from EMPLOYEE", estring.ToString)
   Dim ds As New DataSet
   Dim dt As New DataTable

   Try
       cnn.Open()
       da.Fill(dt)
       cnn.Close()
       cnn.Dispose()
      ' (and so one).....
   ```

The connection established and I'm happy!
You were right about .NET OLE DB Provider for Firdbird (not working with Interbase), thank you all for the help.

I hope that this thread will help others with this problem.